# Getting error when Alfresco community edition 5.0.d is deploying on Geronimo 3.0

Tags: linux, apache, jakarta-ee, alfresco, geronimo

**When I am deploying** 
[Alfresco community edition 5.0.d](https://process.alfresco.com/ccdl/?file=release/community/5.0.d-build-00002/alfresco-community-5.0.d.zip)
**had following error**

***Error when deploying on geronimo***

```
The application was not deployed.
web.xml for web app alfresco includes security elements but Geronimo deployment plan is not provided or does not contain element necessary to configure security accordingly.

at org.apache.geronimo.web25.deployment.AbstractWebModuleBuilder.basicInitContext(AbstractWebModuleBuilder.java:453) 
at org.apache.geronimo.web25.deployment.AbstractWebModuleBuilder.initContext(AbstractWebModuleBuilder.java:436)
at org.apache.geronimo.j2ee.deployment.SwitchingModuleBuilder.initContext(SwitchingModuleBuilder.java:168)
at org.apache.geronimo.j2ee.deployment.EARConfigBuilder.buildConfiguration(EARConfigBuilder.java:686) 
at org.apache.geronimo.deployment.Deployer.deploy(Deployer.java:256) 
at org.apache.geronimo.deployment.Deployer.deploy(Deployer.java:140) 
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor80.invoke(Unknown Source) 
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.ReflectionMethodInvoker.invoke(ReflectionMethodInvoker.java:34)
at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanOperation.invoke(GBeanOperation.java:131) 
at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstance.invoke(GBeanInstance.java:883) 
at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.basic.BasicKernel.invoke(BasicKernel.java:245) 
at org.apache.geronimo.deployment.plugin.local.AbstractDeployCommand.doDeploy(AbstractDeployCommand.java:116) 
at org.apache.geronimo.deployment.plugin.local.DistributeCommand.run(DistributeCommand.java:61) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

### Server Info

***Server:***

1. Version         3.0.0
2. Build           2012.07.03-20:43:28.321+0800
3. Start Time      Wed Jun 03 21:49:00 IST 2015
4. Up Time         13 hours 50 minutes 30 seconds

***Operating System:***

1. Architecture            i386
2. Name                    Linux
3. Version                 2.6.32-504.16.2.el6.x86_64
4. Patch Level             unknown
5. Locale                  en_US

***JVM:***

1. Java Version            1.7.0_79
2. Java Vendor             Oracle Corporation
3. Node                    chaminda.alfresco.akaza/127.0.0.1
4. Current Memory Used     174.76 MB
5. Most Memory Used        239.99 MB
6. Total Memory Allocated  253.5 MB
7. Available Processors    4

***System Property values for the Server JVM***

1. java.awt.graphicsenv    sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment
2. java.awt.printerjob     sun.print.PSPrinterJob
3. java.class.path
   /opt/geronimo-tomcat7-javaee6-3.0.0/lib/commons-cli.jar
   /opt/geronimo-tomcat7-javaee6-3.0.0/lib/geronimo-cli.jar
   /opt/geronimo-tomcat7-javaee6-3.0.0/lib/geronimo-hook.jar
   /opt/geronimo-tomcat7-javaee6-3.0.0/lib/geronimo-main.jar
   /opt/geronimo-tomcat7-javaee6-3.0.0/lib/geronimo-rmi-loader.jar
   /opt/geronimo-tomcat7-javaee6-3.0.0/lib/karaf-jaas-boot.jar
   /opt/geronimo-tomcat7-javaee6-3.0.0/lib/agent/transformer.jar
4. java.class.version  51.0
5. java.endorsed.dirs
               /opt/geronimo-tomcat7-javaee6-3.0.0/lib/endorsed
               /opt/jdk1.7.0_79/jre/lib/endorsed
6. java.ext.dirs    /opt/jdk1.7.0_79/jre/lib/ext
                    /usr/java/packages/lib/ext
7. java.home                    /opt/jdk1.7.0_79/jre
8. java.io.tmpdir               /opt/geronimo-tomcat7-javaee6-3.0.0/var/temp
9. java.library.path               /usr/java/packages/lib/i386 /lib /usr/lib
10. java.runtime.name              Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
11. java.runtime.version           1.7.0_79-b15
12. java.specification.name        Java Platform API Specification
13. java.specification.vendor      Oracle Corporation
14. java.specification.version     1.7
15. java.util.prefs.PreferencesFactory
16. java.vendor-           Oracle Corporation
17. java.version-          1.7.0_79

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an another solution. I tried out install via linux terminal using "`yum install`" command. That was successful.

Comment: What package(s) did you have to install?

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware with Geronimo 3.0, but i think this server is not supported by alfresco.In official documentation of alfresco you will find steps for installing alfresco in Jboss,Tomcat or Weblogic.

In case of above mentioned error ,In side war file of alfresco there is one `web.xml`.The elements of that file is not matching with your server.You may need to change that file from war,even after changing that you will face some issues, Which you will need to resolve.

There are some links on forum you may find that usefull.

https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/installation-upgrades-configuration-integration/installation-upgrades/startup-fails-geronimo

http://forums.alfresco.com/forum/installation-upgrades-configuration-integration/installation-upgrades/alfresco-geronimo-0

https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/installation-upgrades-configuration-integration/installation-upgrades/alfresco-geronimo

Comment: I refered above links but unfortunately I couldn't find exact reson and the solution.